SQLAlchemy-Utils Aggregated Attributes: How to apply filter before aggregating to create an aggregated field?
from sqlalchemy_utils import aggregated


class Thread(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thread'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))

    @aggregated('comments', sa.Column(sa.Integer))
    def comment_count(self):
        return sa.func.count('1')

    comments = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Comment',
        backref='thread'
    )


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
    thread_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Thread.id))
    active = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)

I want the comment_count field to be count of ONLY active comments, instead of ALL comments. Is it possible?
The example is based off of the documentation: https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html

You need declerative_base and sa in order to be able to do that which you can find more information about them here.
from sqlalchemy_utils import aggregated
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thread(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thread'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))

    @aggregated('comments', sa.Column(sa.Integer))
    def comment_count(self):
        return sa.func.count(sa.case([(Comment.active == True, 1)]))

    comments = sa.orm.relationship(
        'Comment',
        backref='thread'
    )

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
    thread_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Thread.id))
    active = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)


sa.case([(Comment.active == True, 1)]) creates a case statement that returns 1 if the comment is active and NULL otherwise.

sa.func.count then counts only the rows where the case statement returns 1, effectively counting only active comments.
This should give you the comment_count as the number of active comments associated with each thread.



Amazing! Thank you so much!
